# window scroll effect using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using three div with id `first,second and third`. Inside my first div I called three class `d,c,e`. I am calling this class in my second div also. When my page scroll down and my third div is in view all these class I called d,c,e should be removed.
I am assuming these should be done through jquery or via jquery animation effect.
Can any one suggest me how to remove all these class from my div.
My class contains .png files.
How to write code for window scroll effect via jquery and remove all these class.

HTML
    
    
    
    
    My page 
    jQuery Parallax Plugin Demo

```
</head>

    <body>

    <div id="first" >
       <div class="d" >
        <div class="c">
            <div class="e"></div>



       This is my first div to display image.


     </div>
     </div>

   </div>
 </div>
<div id="second">
</div>
<div id="third">
</div> 

 </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
 @charset "utf-8";
#first, #second{
    width: 100%;
 }
 #first{

    background:url('images/rc1.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 160px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
     perspective: 1px;

}
#first .d{
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
    width:=218px;
    height: 73px;
    left: auto;
    top: 10%;
    background: url('images/Logo.png') top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x:50px;

}
#first .c{
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
    width: =774px;
    height: 209px;
    left: auto;
    top: 120%;
    /*width:=137px;
    height:88px;*/
    background: url('images/big_text.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x:339px;
}
 #first .e{
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
    width: =127px;
    height: 37px;
    left:auto;
    top: 180%;
    background: url('images/scroll_text.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 680px;
}
```

Comment: @rene I understand. I will try to fix all problems at once on a question edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shall do the trick using window scroll and the third element position

```js
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
  
    var elemTop = $("#third").offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $("#third").height();
  
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    // element in window viewport remove the classes
    if(elemTop <= docViewBottom && $("#first").find('.d').length > 0)
    {
      console.log("no more classes for the first div");
      $("#first").find('.d, .c, .e').removeClass();
     }
     // element is not more in window viewport and the divisions have no class then
     // add these classes
     else if((elemTop > docViewBottom || elemBottom < docViewTop) 
             && $("#first").find('.d').length == 0)
     {
       console.log("classes back to first div");
         $("#first div:eq(0)").addClass("d");
         $("#first div:eq(1)").addClass("c");
         $("#first div:eq(2)").addClass("e");
     }
    
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
#first, #second{
    width: 100%;
 }
 #first{

    background:url('images/rc1.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 160px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
     perspective: 1px;
    border: 1px solid red;

}

 #second{

    background:url('images/rc1.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 160px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
     perspective: 1px;
    border: 1px solid blue;

}

 #third{

    background:url('images/rc1.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 160px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
     perspective: 1px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;

}

#first .d{
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
    width:218px;
    height: 73px;
    left: auto;
    top: 10%;
    background: url('images/Logo.png') top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x:50px;

}
#first .c{
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
    width: 774px;
    height: 209px;
    left: auto;
    top: 120%;
    /*width:=137px;
    height:88px;*/
    background: url('images/big_text.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x:339px;
}
 #first .e{
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
    width: 127px;
    height: 37px;
    left:auto;
    top: 180%;
    background: url('images/scroll_text.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 680px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first" >
       <div class="d" >
        <div class="c">
            <div class="e"></div>



       This is my first div to display image.


     </div>
     </div>

   </div>

<div id="second">
</div>
<div id="third">
</div>
```

Comment: its is working for scroll down but when i scroll up again all child class are removed i want my class back again when scroll up.how to do that one .

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using JQuery. The below code removes all the classes inside "first" div

```
$('#first').children('div').removeClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//updated
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>    
    $(window).scroll(function () {        
        if ($("#first").offset().top + $("#first").height() < $(document).scrollTop()) {
            var obj = $('#first').children('div');
            if (obj.hasClass("d")) {
                obj.removeClass();
            }
            obj = obj.children('div');
            if (obj.hasClass("c")) {
                obj.removeClass();
            }
            obj = obj.children('div');
            if (obj.hasClass("e")) {
                obj.removeClass();
            }
        } else {
            var obj = $('#first').children('div');
            if (obj.hasClass("d") == false) {
                obj.addClass("d");
            }
            obj = obj.children('div');
            if (obj.hasClass("c") == false) {
                obj.addClass("c");
            }
            obj = obj.children('div');
            if (obj.hasClass("e") == false) {
                obj.addClass("e");
            }
        }
    });


</script>
```

Comment: its is working little bit but when i scroll back up all child class are removed i want my class back again when scroll up.how to do that one do i need to add class again

Comment: that was not mentioned in question.I will change code in few minutes